# angular2-seed different endpoints for dev and prod for http

Tags: angular, angular2-http

In angular2-seed I can find:

> If you have different environments and you need to configure them to
>   use different end points, settings, etc. you can use the files dev.ts
>   or prod.ts in./tools/env/. The name of the file is environment you
>   want to use.

But how is this actually done?  I would like to have a production environment where the server side api (using ruby on rails) is the same domain as the angular2 app, but on the client I have http://localhost:3000 for the server but http://localhost:5555 for the angular2 development.

How do I actually configure that?  Thanks for an example.